# .htaccess breaks with multiple redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just replaced an old website with a newer one. I am now trying to redirect old page URLs to new ones via the .htaccess file. When I enter a single redirect, it works as expected. But if I add in a second one, it all breaks and I receive an Internal Server Error on the site.

This is the code put into the .htaccess file:

Redirect 301 /wordpress /?page=home
Redirect 301 /cadcam.php /?page=process

To reiterate, one redirect works, multiple redirects breaks the site. Any suggestions?

Additional info... GoDaddy is the website host. And I'm using Notepad++ to edit the file via FileZilla.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Notepad++. The breaks between lines weren't actual line breaks. When opening the .htaccess file in Windows notepad, all the lines were running together, thus breaking the site. After creating the line breaks in notepad, everything worked as expected.

Comment: beware: if you edit something in windows, then uploading it to a server (usually linux), your line breaks and encodings may break. always use a dedicated ide / editor. my guess is that you just did not know that notepad++ could be configured in a way the line breaks worked correct